# how to get the value of field by foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables :

**FAQS :**

- id
- qn
- An
- cat_id (foreign key)

**Faqcat :**

- id
- name

I want to display the field "name" by foreign key in the first table.

Please help me.

Comment: thanks for your reply then how to echo name?

Comment: search for `JOIN`. read and understand it.

Comment: you should provide the code that you have tried so far ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("select * from faqs as a Join faqcats as b ON a.cat_id = b.id where question like '%$term%'"  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT a.name ,  a.id ,b.An , b.qn FROM Faqcat a JOIN FAQS b ON a.id = b.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `faqcat`.`name` from `faqcat` join `faqs` on `faqcat`.`id`=`faq`.`cat_id`");
if(mysql_num_rows($query))
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))
    {
        echo $row->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `**id**` with the cat_id that you want to get its name :

```
$ID = "**id**";

$SQL = "SELECT cat.name AS name, faq.cat_id  AS id
FROM FAQS faq
JOIN Faqcat cat ON(faq.cat_id = cat.id)
WHERE faq.cat_id = '".$ID."'";
```